# Debugging a Java server with two game clients in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, server

I am building an artificial intelligence agent for an existing board game and having difficulty figuring out how to debug this Java code in Eclipse.

The existing game consists of a server that is run and listens for client connection. Once two clients connect, the game is automatically run to completion based on the AI in the client.  I have source files for all elements.

I would like to be able to debug one of the clients so I can work on it.  The issue is that, if I simply run the server and connect the first client, then debug the second, Eclipse skips all breakpoints.  If I run the server as a remote debugging server, then run a remote debugging configuration on a client in Eclipse, I can step through the server code, but once it's waiting for the second client to connect, it just stops.  At this point, I can't figure out how to connect the second client.

How can I debug an application with this configuration? A server, one connected client and my second client that I want debugging information for.

Thank you!